# Android XML whitepaper

Tags: xml, android, mobile

I am looking for resources concerning Android's use of XML - not how to's, but technical articles or whitepapers concerning the XML architecture in Android. Why were things designed the way they were, what considerations were made - all specific to the XML part.

If this is not available, I'm also interested in general use of XML in mobile computing. Does the iPhone use XML in the same way?

Can anyone point me to some good articles/websites/books/whitepapers/videos ?

Comment: Android uses XML extensively to describe UI layouts and other project requirements.

Comment: @Alnitak: exactly, and what I'm looking for is documentation concerning why they did what they did with XML, the things they were trying to solve, how they decided upon their namespaces, schema, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know that there's anything published or openly available on this subject. Your best option is to contact some of the Android guys at Google and see if they might feel like releasing any of their internal specs.

Comment: That's what I did - didn't get a response. Since I got no other answers on my question (which actually got voted down) I'll accept your answer.